# selenium how to block url ads from loading or stop page from loading C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I would like to speed up page loading. One of the biggest bottlenecks is advertisements and click tracking services. Is there a way to selectively block a browser from loading them, via Selenium Firefox (I also use Chrome)?

Alternatively, is there a way to stop the page from loading so that I can proceed with `IWebElement.Click()` commands? Currently I have to wait for the entire page to load before calling a `IWebElement.Click()` command.

Lets use espn.go.com as an example. It calls www.googletagservices.com during page load. Could I somehow block this unnecessary call?

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

    namespace SeleniumTest
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class TestFixtureStopAdsOrBypass
        {
            [Test]
            public void StackoverflowExample()
            {
                IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://espn.go.com/");

                driver.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Disabling ads
   Selenium allows you to add any browser extension to browser (including AdBlock, AdBlock+, uBlock). Run tests with such extension and you won't see the ads.
2. Don't wait till page loaded
   Firefox solution:

```java
firefoxProfile.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
```

<sub>Both features are implemented in this java project: https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests</sub>